# Partition invisible on Windows, not on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, ntfs

I have Windows 7 64b installed and recently also installed Ubuntu 12.04
Problem: 2 of 4 Partitions on the same harddrive are not visible in Windows.

Here is some info:

```
$ df -T

Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7      ext4      77535900   8437852  65159316  12% /
/dev/sda5      fuseblk   51199120  45194668   6004452  89% /media/Programs
/dev/sda6      fuseblk  307202928 244391628  62811300  80% /media/Data
/dev/sda1      fuseblk   51199120  49790596   1408524  98% /media/Windows




$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x18961895

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   102398309    51199123+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       102398371   976751999   437176814+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       102398373   204796619    51199123+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       204796683   819202544   307202931   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       819202608   976751999    78774696   83  Linux
```

**sda7 and sda6** are not visible in Windows.
I don't care about sda7 too much, but I really need sda6 on both OS's

Thank you!

Comment: /dev/sda6 is configured as a *nix swap space you would be able to use in Windows, or at least I have no idea how it could be possible.  I am assuming you are trying to use the same space for both OS's?  /dev/sda7 is configured with ext4 there are tools that will allow you to mount it under 7 but I am not sure how reliable they are.

Comment: Why do you think windows should "see" linux filesystem? There's very bad situation in W with filesystems: it knows just "three with half" (vfat, ntfs, exfat and partially udf). The same with swap. If you computer is powerful enough and you use W just for 1-2 applikation, it's better for you to setup W under VirtualBox.

Comment: Define 'invisible'. Where are you looking for these partitions in Windows and what did you expect to see?

Comment: A Windows tool was able to show 2 Partitions where the files are not accessible. The partitions also don't show up in any file explorer.
I expect to see at least sda6 since it still has all data that was there when I used it on just Windows. I can see all files under Linux.

Comment: If your sda6 really have W filesystem, you simply should change FS-flag by `fdisk`. Once I've meet same problem: even been formatted to ntfs partition was "invisible" in W because of wrong FS flag (but linux don't care about it).

Comment: I did that now, thank you.
I will try to boot from Windows now. :)

Comment: You will be able to post an answer to your question after a given period. It would be appreciated if you come back and post your answer and accept it as the solution after that period is over :)

Comment: I don't get what the self-answer-timeout is good for but i will come back and post the answer.

Comment: @HansWürstchen: It's meant to allow other users a chance to post answers. I believe when you cross 100 rep here that restriction will be removed.

Comment: [Make Linux Partition Visible in Windows](http://www.2012teamtech.com/make-linux-partition-visible-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, thanks to @Eddy_Em!

My sda6 partition was a Windows file system and still had all files on it.
I must have accidently marked it as 'swap' during the installation of Ubuntu.
The good thing is: The partition was not changed, it just had a false flag.

Changing the filesystem type back to NTFS (using linux) does the trick:

> $ **sudo fdisk /dev/sda6**
>   > Command (m for help): **t**
>   > Partition number (1-7): **6**
>   > Hex code (type L to list codes): **7**
>   > Changed system type of partition 6 to 7 (HPFS/NTFS/exFAT)
>   > Command (m for help): **w**